# How to over-write python log for multiple attempts

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, logging, overwrite

I currently have a user-interface that shows a slideshow of images. The user is able to draw a box over the image and the coordinates of the box are stored in mylog. File_name is the specific image name where the box was drawn. There is a next and previous button for the user to go through the images. The drawn box stays on the image as the user moves forward or backward but the user can also click and drag a new box and the original box automatically deletes.[GUI Example with red box drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdZZd.png) I was wondering if there is a way to overwrite the log every time the user re-draws the box on an image so that only the final box coordinates is show on the log? Let me know if the code is confusing but I added the parts that have to do with the log.

```
 logger = logging.getLogger()
 file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="mylog.log", mode="a")
 formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
 file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
 logger.addHandler(file_handler)
 logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
 logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
 logger.propagate = False
 # to prevent multiple prints


      if file_name in self.loaded_boxes:
            p1, p2 = self.current_drag_box
            if p1 is not None and p2 is not None:
                logging.debug(
                    f"{file_name} box drawn at {self.loaded_boxes[file_name]}"
                )


    # print(message)
    logging.debug([evt.x, evt.y])
    logging.debug([message])
```

Comment: use `filemode='w'` in your basicConfig , it will overwrite the previous logs

Comment: 2021-10-18 13:05:26,484 - PIL.TiffImagePlugin - DEBUG - tag: Orientation (274) - type: short (3) - value: b'\x00\x01'
2021-10-18 13:05:26,484 - PIL.TiffImagePlugin - DEBUG - tag: ExifIFD (34665) - type: long (4) - value: b'\x00\x00\x00&'    I get this error in my log when I change it

Comment: @new2python: Have you tried using `filemode='wb'` (write bytes)?

Comment: Hello, I have. That has also not worked, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Try changing `mode="a"` to `mode="w"` and add `logging.shutdown()` after `logging.debug([message])`.  Why don't you just use simple file operation instead of using `logging` module for such simple logging feature?